# Javascript , ajax and memory usage

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, memory-management, ram

To simplify my problem I suppose that I have an application that turns on intranet on the client. I suppose that the application has one single page and I am using ajax to interact with the server. I am using ajax for instance to download byte files (3Mo for each byte file as ajax object response from server), *these byte files are drawn on canvas later on*.

My questions are

1- Where are located these object response, is it on RAM, or hard disk?

2- If it is on RAM: When I do the second ajax call to download other files, I notice that my browser memory usage goes higher with every call, how can I clear these old objects response downloaded?

PS: I am sure they are stored somewhere because I can see old ajax response objects when I press F12 on the browser and I go to Network section. Thank you in advance and sorry for my English.

Comment: What is a "byte file"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript memory management pitfalls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519114/javascript-memory-management-pitfalls)

Comment: @Pointy array of bytes

Answer (score 4):

Some people vote to close but sometimes they don't take time to read the question they just link to old links from 2009 thinking they answered your question, or perhaps I was not clear enough, anyway, I found out the problem of why my memory goes up, for those who had or will have the same problem, I was using some methods of jquery that leads to memory leaks.

How I discovered the problem :

1. I deleted all the instructions that occur after receiving the ajax responses, I only left the ajax calls. Result => No memory leaks

   for(i=0;i<120;i++){ //am not using the 'for' loop, it is just an example
   $.ajax({

   ```
   }).done(function(){
    // i deleted all this 
   });
   ```

   }
2. So the problem occurs with my code. Elimination principle : I started to delete line by line to figure out which line causes the problem : Result => **.append() and html() leads to memory leaks** , so i replace them with javascript innerHTML or appendChild() js => problem solved